# WCF service client with cert auth, works when debug, but not live

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-config, certificate

Im using a certificate authenticated WCF service. I works when in VS debugmode, but when i publish and run it won't work.

The cerificatesd are stored in CurrentUser/TrustedPeople.
This is my config behavior-section:

```
<behavior name="LoadClientCert">
    <clientCredentials>
        <clientCertificate findValue="CN=Certificate1"
                        storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="TrustedPeople"
                        x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName" />
        <serviceCertificate>
          <defaultCertificate findValue="CN=Certificate2"
                        storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="TrustedPeople"
                        x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName" />
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="None"
                        revocationMode="NoCheck" />
        </serviceCertificate>
      </clientCredentials>
</behavior>
```

Error message: *Request Error
The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details.*

My guess is  that the IIS user don't have permissions to use the certificate. But that is only guessing.

And where can i find that server log? i tried event viewer but i didn't find anything. I also added this to my config without luck(its empty after trying the solution):

```
<system.diagnostics>
<sources>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
    <listeners>
             <add name="messages"
             type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
             initializeData="f:\logs\messages.svclog" />
      </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
</system.diagnostics>
<diagnostics>
<messageLogging 
     logEntireMessage="true" 
     logMalformedMessages="false"
     logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" 
     logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false"
     maxMessagesToLog="3000"
     maxSizeOfMessageToLog="2000"/>
</diagnostics>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using self signed certificates?

Comment: Yes they are self-signed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using 2 was SSL i.e. securing the transport channel with SSL and authenticating your client with SSL then the certificates should be placed as follows:

For Server Certificate (.pfx file):

Install the certificate in Local Machine Personal folder.

For Client Certificates:

On Server machine(.cer file):
Install the client certificate in Local Machine --> Trusted People Store

On Client Machine (.pfx file):
Install the client certificate in Local User --> Personal Store

Also if the server certificate is self signed make sure to use the below code on your client side just before invoking the service method:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, error) =>
                                                                                 {
                                                                                     return true;
                                                                                 };
```

UPDATE:

[How to enable Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx)

Comment: Does the placement of the certificates matter? as long as it is specified in the config where to look? The service uses regular http://

Comment: Yes the certificates need to be placed in the appropriate store.

Comment: But where do i put them if i dont use ssl?

Comment: I have specified the stores where to install the certificates. If you do not wish to use SSL then just comment the serviceCertificate element and clientCertificate element in your config which should disable remove 2 way SSL

Comment: I'we got it to work on my localhost IIS but when i publish it on the a live server it still gives me the same error. I the problem before was that the csertificates was in the wrong store and i had to grant the apppool permissions to the cert. So what i'we got on my web server is: clientcert in the LocalComputer/Personal and the server cert in LocalComputer/Trusted people.  I know this is not much to go on but, it still says "Bad request" - "Error message: Request Error The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details." Any suggestions what to do now?

Comment: the client certificate needs to be in the trusted people store on your web server. Are you getting a 400 Bad request error? If that is the case then you need to enable tracing to identify what is causing the bad request

Comment: Got it to work. My system admin had not included the webserver into the VPN. Thanks for your time!